# Do you have to free strings passed to exported C functions in Emscripten?

Tags: emscripten

I found out through the Emscripten wiki ([Interacting with code](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Interacting-with-code)) that C functions called from javascript with `ccall` or `cwrap` should have `char*` as argument or return type when being passed or returning a string.

I am not very experienced in C (the rest of my project is written in C++) but I know you normally have to manually free dynamic strings in C. Is this the case when passing a string from javascript to a C function, and if so, how should this be done?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you can get your C++ code to take care of the memory allocation and freeing for you.  For example if you pass in a literal string (in quotes), it will be freed after the function returns.

For variable strings, I recommend that you use std::string (as you probably normally do), and when you pass it into an emscripten function, just call the c_str() method on it to convert it.

For example:

```
    my_js_function(my_string.c_str());
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to handle std::string to c-string conversions and the like. But I wasn't talking about passing a string from C++ to javascript.

I want to do it the other way around: Call a C function with a string parameter from javascript

Comment: I see -- I haven't tried going in that direction with strings yet.  You shouldn't have to do anything special on the C side; if you use Module._malloc() in JS, you should obviously run Module._free() after the call.  If you're using the buffer from existing strings, JS should take care of the memory, but more generally I'm not sure how to convert the strings to a char*.  If I figure something out, I'll post a new answer (and let us know if you do figure it out in the meantime!)

Comment: I already tested calling a function taking a `const char*` from javascript, there is no conversion to be done manually, you just do `ccall("func", null, ["string"], "<data>");`. I'll try calling it in a loop some times, that should show whether it leaks memory.

Comment: Okay, it seems there is no memory leaked in this case. I will still try out a few things other later today or in the next days – if the same thing with `char*` without const as argument type leaks memory when not freeing it manually and whether passing a non-const string into a c function gives the c function the ability to modify the javascript variable.